# TextBlock - Combination of OpticalMarginAlignment and TextTrimming

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I need to use OpticalMarginAlignment property in order to remove unnecessary left and right margin of TextBlock, however, I also have to use TextTrimming property due to very long text which I want to cut it and there is a problem. OpticalMarginAlignment also removes space between text and three dots and it does not look good. Is there any approach how to solve it?

```
<TextBlock
    Text="Lorem ipsum long long long long long long text"
    OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings"
    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

[image]

Comment: Good question. But unfortunately they don't seem to work well when combined together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you should use negative margins to mimic OpticalMarginAlignments in this case.

Comment: It is not possible because each letter has different margin and it also depends on used font.